# sys.database_principals is not executed in current database if called from sp procedure (stored in master)

Tags: sql-server, view, catalog

I would like to print out database users of an actual database in a SP procedure (see the code of `sp_PrintUsers` below), however, for some reason it print out database users of master. It seems that it is a general behavior of SP procedure for all database-level views despite the fact that any database-level SQL statement is executed in the actual database. If we print out the `DB_NAME` that it is clearly not master, so what is wrong?

Is there any workaround?

```
use [master]
go
create procedure sp_PrintUsers
as
begin
    SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName
    select name from sys.database_principals;
end
go

use [actual_database]
go

exec sp_PrintUsers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the select dynamically as in:

```
EXEC('select name from sys.database_principals;');
```

If that does not help build the query to reference the catalog view with a three part name.

Comment: Thanks it works. It seems that any dynamic T-SQL is executed in actual database and static T-SQL in master database. Really strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
use [master]
go
create procedure sp_PrintUsers
as
begin
    declare @dbname varchar(30) = DB_NAME()
    EXEC ('select name from ' + @dbname + '.sys.database_principals');        
end
go

use [actual_database]
go

exec sp_PrintUsers
```